# How to get XStream to map back to a typed List?

Tags: java, json, orm, xstream, oxm

I'm using XStream to map some JSON back into Java objects. I'll be dealing with a JSON string that might look like this:

```
{
    "widgets":[
    {
        "widget_name": "Kenny",
        "widget_type": "Character"
    },
        "widget_name": "Apple",
        "widget_type": "Fruit"
    }
    ]
}
```

**Update:** I *believe* this JSON could be interpreted as:

> This JSON represents an un-named object that contains a `widgets` object. The `widgets` object, in turn, contains an array of other un-named objects. Each of these un-named objects contain two properties: `widget_name` and `widget_type`.

Each `Widget` in this `widgetlist` corresponds to a POJO:

```
public class Widget {
    private String name;
    private String type;

    // ...etc.
}
```

I'd like the above JSON string to map back to a `List<Widget>`, but I can't seem to figure out how to alias the class correctly:

```
XStream xs = new XStream();
xs.alias("widgetlist", List.class); // Not a List<Widget> !
```

**How can I get the `xs` mapper to translate `widgetlist` into a `List<Widget>`?** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code worked for me, however the JSON generated is not similar to the one you have. If you were to use the `JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver` instead of the `JettisonMappedXmlDriver` you would get the same JSON as you have in your question. Downside of this is that the `JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver` cannot read JSON and will give an `UnsupportedOperationException` if you try.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES); 
xstream.alias("widgetlist", List.class);
xstream.alias("widget", Widget.class);
List<Widget> widgetlist = new ArrayList<Widget>();
Widget w1 = new Widget("Kenny", "Character");
Widget w2 = new Widget("Apple", "Fruit");
widgetlist.add(w1);
widgetlist.add(w2);
String serialized = xstream.toXML(widgetlist);
System.out.println(serialized);
List<Widget> unserialized = (List<Widget>)xstream.fromXML(serialized);
System.out.println("Size: "+unserialized.size());
```

The generated XML by `JettionMappedXmlDriver`

```
{
    "widgetlist": {
        "widget": [
            {
                "name": "Kenny",
                "type": "Character"
            },
            {
                "name": "Apple",
                "type": "Fruit"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Interpretation**

The JSON is the `DROP_ROOT_MODE` version of the below JSON(un-named object, if you like).
You can therefore look at it as an un-named object that contains a **list of** `Widget`. The `Widget` object still have the same structure as described in the question.

```
public class WidgetList {
    List<Widget> widgets;

    public WidgetList() {
        this.widgets = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

*Xstream settings*

```
    xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
    xstream.alias("widgets", List.class);
    xstream.addImplicitCollection(WidgetList.class, "widgets");
    xstream.alias("widgets", Widget.class);
    xstream.alias("widgetsL", WidgetList.class);
```

*JSON Output*

```
{
    "widgetsL": {
        "widgets": [
            {
                "name": "Kenny",
                "type": "Character"
            },
            {
                "name": "Apple",
                "type": "Fruit"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @atomman (+1) - Unofrtunately, this morning I realized that my JSON string at the top of my question was incorrect, so I edited it to reflect the actual (correct) JSON I'm dealing with.

Comment: Well, the only way I see that can reproduce that JSON is by using the `JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver` with the `DROP_ROOT` mode activated. But as I stated in my answer, this `Driver` doesn't support unserialization. Unfortunately, the `JettisonMappedXmlDriver` does not support this mode, since it requires a strict structure. `{"ObjectName":{"fieldName": "fieldValue", "fieldName2": "fieldValue"}}`. I'm sorry, but I'm not able to find a solution with your current JSON, so my only advise would be changing the JSON structure or parsing it yourself with a custom `StaxReader`.

Comment: fair enough! I think I'll try changing the JSON. One last followup: I updated the original question with an interpretation of what I *believe* the JSON example represents. Can you read that description and tell me if I'm accurate or correct me if I'm wrong? Thanks again for all your help so far (and again, +1)!

Comment: I think the more correct interpretation is: The JSON represents an un-named object that contains a **list of** widgets. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again - pure awesomeness!